# Measure browser perfomance in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, google-chrome

We have pretty loaded web application which updates lots of data (stock quotes) on the web page via websockets without latency. It brings problems with perfomance to those clients that have slow computers.

We can change framerate of the application and put some aggregation and latency (similar to what angular does) but first we have to detect if user really needs it (has troubles with perfomance).

**Is it possible to detect troubles with prefomance in browser via js? May be there some global properties in Chrome from which we can get current perfomance statistics?**

Comment: Chrome supports the Resource Timing API (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network) and have links to the specifications (http://www.w3.org/TR/resource-timing/) as well as some examples.

Answer (score 0):

Check `window.performance` (NavTiming) javascript API, this is new HTML5 API.
See availability at http://caniuse.com/#feat=nav-timing